# Create folder on Google drive (Android)

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

i need to access the google drive storage of logged in user. For now i can fetch his name and his Email, Cover picture and Avatar. I can even ask for accessing the drive storage. But i can't get it managed to create files/folders on Gdrive.

The developers page is giving me this code to create folder:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
```

But i am sure it can't just be that easy.

```
fileMetadata.setName
```

can not be resolved for me. I am sure i am missing something.

This is what i do while loading my GoogleApiClient

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

I don't want to use hidden app folder, instead, i want that user see the app folder, and could easy see what's inside. I have a button, and when user click on it, specific file that is saved locally should be uploaded to drive. Later on i will add maybe auto sync, but for now manual upload would be enough to understand. Thanks!!!

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [**Drive API for Android**](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#top_of_page), note that working with folders has slight differences when compared to Google Drive API. Folders in the Drive API for Android are specialized resources within `metadata` and a `DriveId` and to create a folder, call `DriveFolder.createFolder` for the root folder. Then, pass the metadata containing the title and other attributes to set the values for the folder.

For a full working example, see the [CreateFolderActivity](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFolderActivity.java) sample in the [Google Drive Android API Demos app](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/).

Comment: I'm so glad to know that those given links were exactly what you needed. Happy coding :)

Comment: CreateFolderActivity <-- the above link is not working.